# PHP not reporting specific error (double opening php tag)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I've just had a hard time finding a bug in my PHP code described below

```
<?php
if(condition...)
    {
     do something...
    }
<?php
...more php
```

Notice that I incorrectly opened a php block again when it was not needed(before the ...more php)

The problem is that PHP is not reporting this error, it's just giving me a blank page. I've set error reporting to E_ALL and ini_set display errors '1'. I was wondering if there is a way to make php report this kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean? PHP does detect that problem and does report the error, if you have errors turned on:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in ### on line #
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very common problem, yet a quite simple one.

That's just error reporting settings.
Your server apparently set up to not to display errors (which is the **only** right behavior on a live server!), but most likely it writing errors in some **log file**.
You have to find out where this file located and peek for errors.

If it's not a live server, you may turn on `display_errors` setting in the php.ini

Comment: I checked my windows/temp/php-errors.log file and this error is not being logged, just some php notices. And I have error reporting set to E_ALL and display errors = 1 in the php file itself(actually an included config file)